# display user profile image of chat sender in django-template

Tags: javascript, django, websocket

All is working good except of the fact that, i am trying to display user profile images of user who sent a chat message in a chat room .
this is what my image patth prints "profilepics/images_g9LwcHF.jpg".
Note i am using django framework

```
<script>

  chatSocket.onmessage=function(e){
    var  tag_img=document.createElement('img');
    var get_user=document.querySelector('#user').value
    var tagname=document.createElement('li');
    var data =JSON.parse(e.data);   

    document.querySelector('.img_tag').src=data.message.sender_img

</script>
```

Dom

```
<img class ="img_tag">
```

This is my consumer.py

```
        messaage_json={
          'user':me.username,
          'message':message_object.message,
          'sender':message_object.sender.username,
          'sender_img':str(message_object.sender.profilepicture),
          'created':str(message_object.created)
        }

        #coverting data to string 
        myResponse={
          "message":messaage_json,

        }
        #broad cast the message event to be send 
        # in the layaer
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,{
                # call the chat_message method
                "type":"chat_message",
                #covert string data to json objects
                "text":json.dumps(myResponse),

            }
        )
```

It prints out the user profile image path in the media file, but cannot display the image using javascript.
Note i am using django .

Answer (score 0):

I do not see you actually injecting the newly created image DOM-node into the DOM, e.g. somewhere you would need to do that for the image to be displayed:

```js
chatSocket.onmessage=function(e){

var data =JSON.parse(e.data);

var tag_img=document.createElement('img');
tag_img.src = data.message.sender_img;

document.querySelector('.img_tag').appendChild(tag_img);
```

Comment: well this what i did in the dom          <div class ="img_tag">
    </div>

Comment: well, but your `document.querySelector('.img_tag')` is a `div`! DIV's don't have a `src` attribute! Your classes/variable names are a bit confusing though =)...

Comment: the ' img'  has been created using document.createElement('img') . and the img has a source attritude. I guess div is not a problem . Because  when i use  {% static 'images/default.png' %}, the image displayed . instead of  data.message.sender_img which is my problem i need a solution .

Comment: "the ' img' has been created using document.createElement('img')" => yes, but it is never added to the DOM with `createElement()`!

Comment: in my dom i  tried  <img class="img_tag" scr=""></img> but still can not display the image . showing a broken patth . but when i tried to test it out using document.querySelector('.img_tag').src="{% static 'images'default.png' %}" the image displays. i use console.log(data.message.sender_img) it print out the image path .Which  means the string is not empty. But  needs a right way to handle it

Comment: any difference if you try to set the `src` with `.setAttribute('src', data.message.sender_img)` instead of `.src`?

Comment: does not , this is what  my image path prints  "profilepics/images_g9LwcHF.jpg", note i am using django frame work

Answer (score 0):

yes i solved the problem . To display the image path, since all uploaded images are stored in django media file , i am to use the following bellow

```
tag_img.src = '/'+'media'+'/'+ data.message.sender_img;
```

Comment: @john...How did you do this? I am having same problem for days now and still could not fixed it. How did you pass profile picture in consumer.py? Please I need help on how to do this.

Comment: @john...this is my code. Thanks.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62750983/websocket-disconnected-connect-call-failed