# Undefined In Console JQuery

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I am working on a website using Django, i am a beginner in Jquery and i am trying to display an image using JQuery, when form is submitted. Image do not display and i am getting an error in console "Undefined".

[image]

[image]

JQuery:

```
var chatHolder = $('#chat-items')
// below is the message I am receiving
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
var chatDataMsg = JSON.parse(e.data)

var profile_pic = $('#avatarImg').attr("src");
console.log(profile_pic);

chatHolder.append("<div class='media w-50 mb-3'>" + "<img src=" + profile_pic + " width='30' height='30' class='rounded-circle mt-1'/>" + "<div class='media-body ml-2'>" + "<div class='bg-light rounded py-2 px-3 mb-2'>" + "<p class='text-small mb-0 text-black'>" + chatDataMsg.message + "</p>" + "</div>" + "<p class='small text-muted'>" + newMonth  +  newDate + "<i class='fa fa-ellipsis-h float-right'></i>" + "</p>" + "</div>" + "</div>")

}
```

Template:

```
<div class="px-4 py-3 chat-box bg-white" id='chat-items' style="height:435px;">
    {% for chat in object.chatmessage_set.all %}
     {% if request.user != chat.user %}
    <!-- Sender Message-->
    <div class="media w-50 mb-3">  
      <img src="{{ chat.user.profile.profile_pic.url }}" id="avatarImg" width="30" height="30" class="rounded-circle mt-1">         
      <div class="media-body ml-2">
        <div class="bg-light rounded py-2 px-3 mb-2">
          <p class="text-small mb-0 text-black">{{ chat.message|emoticons }}</p>
        </div>
        <p class="small text-muted">
        {{ chat.timestamp|date:'M j, Y,  g:i a' }}
        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h float-right"></i>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

<form id='form' method='POST' action="." class="chatbox-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input = "submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: Please show code instead of pictures of code

Comment: @mplungjan... The code is the picture I uploaded. The template and the console is what I uploaded. Check the template in my question.

Comment: You have a problem with an image. I assume the URL is somewhere in the object you posted as an image instead of actual code.

Comment: Does `avatarImg` is available when you try to access it ? because currently your image is under `if-statement` .

Comment: @Swati...Yes avatarImg is available, but when I render this in jquery I get undefined. When I reload my browser then the image display.

Comment: @mplungjan... The code in my question is what I am using, I just screenshot the error so it will be easier to understand. Please check on my code: Template and Jquery I updated

Comment: Your question is likely NOT an issue with the socket and not an issue with the template. So it is not a python, django or CSRF issue. If you now do as I ask and 1. Click edit. 2. Click the icon shaped like `[<>]` and then add a [mcve] with RENDERED HTML and a `var chatDataMsg = JSON.parse(\`Some actual JSON\`)` then we can take it from there

Comment: @mplungjan... I do not understand what you mean. I know the error is not coming from socket, but jquery. What code do you want? I have updated all code in template.

Comment: We want a [mcve] - so post view-source HTML instead of template and add example data

Comment: @mplungjan...I am trying to update all my codes but i get an error "most coded" can you look at this link, it contains all my code. Thanks.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62750983/websocket-disconnected-connect-call-failed